# let $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ , $a\in A$ , function $f$ be differentiable at $a$

Tags: derivatives

> let $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ , $a\in A$ , function $f$ be differentiable at $a$
>
> **Claim:**
>
> if there exists a right neighborhood: $N^+_{\epsilon}(a)$
>
> and  there exists a left neighborhood: $N^-_{\epsilon}(a)$
>
> such that : for every $x \in N^+_{\epsilon}(a) \cap A$ implies that $f(a)<f(x)$
>
> such that : for every $x \in N^-_{\epsilon}(a) \cap A$ implies that $f(a)>f(x)$
>
> then : $f'(a) >0$

is it right ? Or must $f'(a)  \geq  0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true, take $f(x)=x^3$ has a counterexample. It is differentiable increasing and $f'(0)=0$. You can jus conclude that $f'(a)\geq 0$.

Comment: @ Tsemo Aristide . so $f'(a)  \geq  0)$is it right ?

Comment: Yes, it is not>.0.